# Surjective implies fixed point?

Tags: general-topology, functions, dynamical-systems

I'm in a discrete dynamical systems class and we have a function $f : [0, \infty) \longrightarrow [0, \infty)$ such that $f$ is surjective, I need a hint to prove that there exists $x_0 \in [0, \infty) \ \text{s.t.} \ f(x_0)=x_0$. I have tried to come up with counterexamples but I can't come up with any function.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume $f$ is continuous. Then either $0$ is a fixed point or $f$ will switch the order of $0$ and $y$ for some $y > 0$. Then look at $f(x) - x$.

Comment: Nope, I can't assume continuity; with continuity the exercise is quite easy and the function u give gives straightforward the answer. Thanks anyways :)

Comment: divide the positive reals in intervals $[n, n+1)$ for integer $n \geq 0$ and then swap intervals $0$ and $1$, $2$ and $3$, etc. Then this function is surjective but has no fixed point.

Comment: There must be *some* assumption on $f$ beyond surjectivity..

Comment: I will ask if $f$ lacks an assumption, as answered in a comment and an answer below confirms me that the proposition is false. Btw, if anyone's interested if we assume continuity it follows easily from Intermediate Value Theorem that there must exist at least one fixed point!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is false. Let $f(x)=(x-2)^{2}$ if $x \neq 1, x \neq 4$. Let $f(1)=4$ and $f(4)=1$. Then you can check that $f$ is surjective but there is no $x$ such that $f(x)=x$.